# How do i get someone from Canonical to contact me or contact them?

Tags: support

How can i get into contact with someone at Canonical? I have submitted contact me forms, and havent been contacted. I have used the link here [MAAS IO](http://maas.io/contact-us) and no one has returned a call. Sure I'm not part of some billion dollar company, but i would at least expect a email in return.

Is there a number in the USA to call and contact Canonical? Forum support is nice and Its a great tool. Once in a while a human being to be in contact with is great.

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/about/contact-us in my experience, be patient

Comment: I have waited about 3 months now...

Comment: Sounds like being in contact with a human once in a while is not a good enough reason for Canonical. Certainly understandable, don't you think? Do you have better reasons?

Comment: @John75077 keep it to the point. Comments regarding a downvote have no place in a question.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to contact members of Canonical.
As you are are contacting people on the business level,
you of course need to have some reasonable approach.

One of them is to use the [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) platform.
Once signed in you can see the mail addresses.
Write a mail to the person you want to talk to.

My personal experiences are quite positive.
I received a response within the same day.
And that happened more than one time.

Another way is to contact via websites.
Leave a comment and wait for a reply.
But in this case you have to be patient.

Here is an example of the websites :
[Dustin Kirkland](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/) | [Mark Shuttleworth](http://markshuttleworth.com/)
(Ubuntu Product and Strategy team)